# Hello, it shows me two letter "L",but i would like to see full letters like "hello" but in this case it tells"he(2"L")o",why? Thank you

Tags: javascript

I have some misunderstanding, when i am running this simple code it shows me two letter "L",but i would like to see full letters vertically like "hello" but in this case it tells"he(2"L")o",why?

```js
var str = "hello"; 
var count = 0; 
while(count < str.length){     
console.log(str[count]);     
count++; 
}
```

Comment: because the console is combining the same log message.... That is what it does.

Comment: in my browser it tells like I have "2 L",so where the problem?

Comment: There is no problem it is saying the same log message was repeated in a row..... since it is the same message it just adds a counter. Make the lines unique and it will not combine it.... `console.log(count, str[count]);`

Comment: Thanks @epascarello,i missed this option.